# Can 'He will be late. It is certain.' be merged into 'He is certain to be late'?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, tense

I was asked in my exam to combine the sentences-
*He will be late.*
and
*It is certain.*

I merged them into-
*He is certain to be late.*

Was it correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what the criteria for doing this task could be but I think "*He is certainly late*" and "*It's a certainity that he is late*" work just as well.

Comment: Your title is different, it uses the future form "he will be late"

Comment: Sorry for that! Correcting it.

Comment: How about 'It is certain **that** he will be late'? No changes to original sentences, just one word added.

Comment: I also liked 'It is certain that he will be late.' but is my sentence correct?

Comment: Surely the correct answer will depend on the instructional materials that were used to prepare for the exam.

Answer (score 2):

Your proposed sentence is perfectly grammatical and does in fact combine the two statements properly.

A google books search for "is certain to be late" produces many examples, including a test question which may be the actual question on your exam, along with an affirmation that your answer is correct.

[image]

[Link](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Oswaal_ICSE_Question_Bank_Class_10_Engli/JMdsEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22is+certain+to+be+late%22&pg=PA183&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score -2):

> "He is certain to be late"

I feel that is **wrong**.

What is "certain"? The thing that is "certain" is the **concept** or sentence "he will be late".

I could say "I am certain that the dog is dead" or "I am certain that the moon is yellow" or "I am certain that two plus two is four."

In these examples, the dog, the moon, two, are **not** the thing that is "certain".

The thing that is "certain" is the concept or sentence "he will be late".

Thus:

> It's a certainty that he will be late.

Or, I am certain he will be late. Or possibly, It's certain that he will be late.

Answer (score -3):

I think the correct answer is 'He is certainly late.' The fact that 'It is certain' is in the present tense can rule over 'He will be late' which is in the future tense. 'He is certain to be late' doesn't sound right according to me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is wrong. "He is certainly late" would be said when "now", he is in fact (now) late.